# How do I animate my window background color?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to fill my window with a uniform color that slowly changes in each frame.

```py
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([400,400])

color = random.randint(0,255)

screen.fill((color))

r_color=10
r_color_change=5

animating=True
while animating:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            animating = False

    r_color += r_color_change
    if r_color > 255 or r_color < 0:
        r_color_change *= -1

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: You should put all your code inside code box

Comment: `screen.fill()` color should be in RGB: `screen.fill((R, G, B))`

Comment: thank you and also I think I have the whole animating part in the last part wrong do you know how to animate a window only? It's fine if you can't, thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A color consists of 3 color channels, red, green and blue. (see [RGB color model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model)). You need to continuously [`fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) the entire screen with the new color in the application loop:

```py
animating=True 
while animating:
    # [...]
    
    screen.fill((r_color, 0, 0))
```

Additionally you should clam the `r_color` value to the range [0, 255]:

```py
screen.fill((r_color, 0, 0))
```

And control the frames per second with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
animating=True 
while animating:
    clock.tick(60)

    # [...]
```

---

Complete example:

```py
import pygame 
import random 

pygame.init() 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([400,400])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

r_color = random.randint(0,255)
r_color_change=5

animating=True 
while animating:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            animating = False

    r_color += r_color_change
    if r_color > 255 or r_color < 0:
        r_color_change *= -1
    r_color = max(0, min(255, r_color))

    screen.fill((r_color, 0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me with this greatly appreciated!